# Why did Rails "touch" all of my database entries?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm working on a Ruby on Rails 3.2 app with a MySQL database on my local machine. To test out some new functionality I was adding, I wrote a script to manually insert about 50,000 records into the database. So far, so good.

The first time I loaded the page with my new functionality after adding these records, Rails loaded each of the records and then updated them, one at a time. This is what my log file looked like:

```
  (0.1ms)  BEGIN
 MyModel Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `my_models` WHERE `my_models`.`part_id` = BINARY 1 LIMIT 1
 SQL (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO `my_models` (`answer_date_time`, `call_date_time`, `caller_id`, `part_id`, `created_at`, `destination`, `employee_id`, `end_date_time`, `length`, `part_user_id`, `price`, `routing`, `source`, `updated_at`) VALUES (NULL, '2013-06-28 13:12:06', NULL, 1, '2013-06-28 13:12:06', NULL, 4, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'incoming', NULL, '2013-06-28 13:12:06')
  (52.6ms)  COMMIT
  (0.0ms)  BEGIN
 MyModel Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `my_models` WHERE `my_models`.`part_id` = BINARY 2 LIMIT 1
 SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO `my_models` (`answer_date_time`, `call_date_time`, `caller_id`, `part_id`, `created_at`, `destination`, `employee_id`, `end_date_time`, `length`, `part_user_id`, `price`, `routing`, `source`, `updated_at`) VALUES (NULL, '2013-06-28 13:12:06', NULL, 2, '2013-06-28 13:12:06', NULL, 4, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'outgoing', NULL, '2013-06-28 13:12:06')
  (70.4ms)  COMMIT
```

And so on, for all 50,000+ records. It took several minutes to complete. I've tried reloading the offending page multiple times after this, though, and Rails hasn't run these queries again.

Does this look normal? Does Rails occasionally need to "poke" new records like this once, and then leave them alone? Or does it look like something's wrong with my code that's going to cause performance problems?

If there are potential problems, I'm unfortunately new to Rails, and I've inherited this app from someone else. Where should I start looking for the code that would produce this kind of behavior?

EDIT: This is the definition of MyModel. I don't know what the comment means...

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  # This model is :dependent => :delete elsewhere
  #  so no :dependents or before/after destroy callbacks without changing other models!
  belongs_to :employee

  validates_uniqueness_of :parts_id

  # snip - class and instance methods
end
```

EDIT 2: This is how I added the records to the database:

I wrote a Ruby script `create_db_data.rb` that looked like this (this isn't the actual script because I don't want to share my company's code, but it works almost exactly the same way):

```
n = 0
for employee in Employee
  for i in (1..10000)
    obj = MyModel.new
    obj.employee_id = employee.id
    obj.answer_date_time = Date.today - i

    n += 1
    obj.part_id = n

    obj.save
  end
end
```

Then I executed `rails r create_db_data.rb` from the command line. After this, the next time I tried to load a page from my app on my dev machine, Rails performed the strange queries that I'm asking about - Rails didn't do anything *as* I added the records, but *afterwards*.

Comment: This definitely doesn't look normal - Rails (ActiveRecord here) does a pretty good job of not doing anything "behind the scenes", though it does have some magic that allows you to shoot yourself in the foot until you get some experience with it. A great first step would be to search your codebase for `MyModel.exists?` with :part_id as an argument - this method is the one that generates the log statements starting with "MyModel Exists". It's hard to tell from here, but it seems like there is some check somewhere that will create a new MyModel if it can't find one with the given "part_id"

Comment: are you sure that those logs are not from when you added the records? did you add them via a rake task? since that looks to me like rails adding and testing the uniqueness validation on each record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess is that it has to do with the `validates_uniqueness_of parts_id` line in `MyModel`'s definition. According to [the documentation for the function](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of),

> When [a] record is created [using `validates_uniqueness_of parts_id`], a check is performed to make sure that no
>   record exists in the database with the given value for the specified
>   attribute (that maps to a column). When the record is updated, the
>   same check is made but disregarding the record itself.

My guess is that since I added the records using `rails r` and not starting the server proper, Rails still wanted to perform the check the first time I actually used the records in the web app.